# Can I delete a file name from a certain point in the name?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that pulls in the file from the server and places it in a folder.

However all I need is the fist part of the file name so I was wondering is there is a way of deleting the rest of the file name from a certain point.

For example `5018228_Prince_+_L$_Mn03_Mx98_Tr00_Tc300__39L_F.psd` is the file name, I don't need the part from the dollar sign `$` onward so it would look like this `5018228_Prince_+_L.psd`

Comment: use a regular expression? Or split the string by `$`? What have you tried doing that isn't working?

Comment: I've tried the split the string and a find & replace but neither have worked

Comment: show what you have tried please and explain what does it mean "doesn't work"

Comment: Why did `split` not work? Can you post the code you tried? You should be able to detach the extension, alter the filename and re-add extensions required.

Comment: The console was not defined

Comment: Can you post the code as console not defined could be from anything. :) Blood from a stone :)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution using Regex**

You can use `regex` with `capturing groups` and get the expected result.

```js
var fileName ="5018228_Prince_+_L$_Mn03_Mx98_Tr00_Tc300__39L_F.psd";

var reqName = fileName.replace(/(.*)\$.*(\.[a-z]*)/,"$1$2");

console.log(reqName);
```

So in the above regex I use 2 capturing groups using `( )` which will be stored in `$1` and `$2` later during replace. So while replacing I use only the captured groups hence omitting the non required (non captured) part of string.

The captured sub-string are as represented below.

```
 (5018228_Prince_+_L)$_Mn03_Mx98_Tr00_Tc300__39L_F(.psd)
//------------------                             -------
//-------^^ this is $1-----------------------------^^ this is $2------------
```